# Does the US have a plan B in case the negotiations with Iran fail?

Tags: united-states, iran, foreign-policy

On October 13, 2021, the [Guardian](https://amp.theguardian.com/world/2021/oct/13/us-and-israel-exploring-plan-b-for-if-iran-does-not-resume-nuclear-talks) talked about a possible "plan B" in case Iran doesn't want to rejoin the negotiations, but did not clarify what that "Plan B" practically means, **have the western officials, specifically, the American ones ever mentioned what is the "plan B" supposed to be?** because it seems way too far fetched that Iran and the US agree as the negotiators repeatedly express their concerns that the negotiations will most likely reach to a dead-end.

Comment: While the first question can be answered with facts, I don't think the next two can be as we simply don't know and it requires speculation about future events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Biden [said](https://www.timesofisrael.com/us-would-use-force-against-iran-as-last-resort-biden-tells-israeli-tv/) without getting into any details that he does not rule out military action "as a last resort".

> US President Joe Biden told Israel’s Channel 12 news that he would use force against Iran as a “last resort” to prevent it from obtaining nuclear weapons, but stressed his preference to negotiate with the Iranians instead.

A written statement later [read](https://www.reuters.com/world/us-israel-sign-joint-pledge-denying-nuclear-weapon-iran-2022-07-14/):

> "The United States stresses that integral to this pledge [towards Israel] is the commitment never to allow Iran to acquire a nuclear weapon, and that it is prepared to use all elements of its national power to ensure that outcome," the statement added. [...]
>
> "The only way to stop a nuclear Iran is if Iran knows the free world will use force," [Biden] said after the signing ceremony.

Comment: Could the "Plan B" be anything between the negotiations and military action?

Comment: @Bootstrap: well, "maximum pressure" sanctions didn't quite work out. Israel and possibly the US as well have be waging a more covert campaign of assassinations and sabotage, but that didn't quite get them to reverse Iran's progress either.

Comment: https://www.atlanticcouncil.org/blogs/iransource/israels-policy-toward-iran-is-failing-by-a-thousand-cuts-heres-why/